# How to implement two different linear gradient borders to an element?

Tags: css, border, linear-gradients, border-image

I really new in CSS, and I have a task to create 2 linear-gradient as a border of a div like in the below image.

I used `border-image` for the inside one but I don't know how to create the other border.

```
border-image: linear-gradient(#EEEEEE ,#666666, #EEEEEE) 1 1% !important;
```

[image: please see the attached picture.]

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you tried creating atleast one of those gradients?

Comment: yes, i use border image for the inside one. border-image: linear-gradient(#EEEEEE ,#666666, #EEEEEE) 1 1% !important;

Comment: @user3493678: You should always add important information like your code etc into the question itself by clicking the [edit] link. Comments can go unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks it's my first post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using an extra pseudo-element:**

I don't think it is possible to do this with just one element (that is, no extra pseudo/real elements) using `border-image` but you can do it using a pseudo-element by setting one border on the parent and the other on the pseudo-element like in the below snippet.

```css
div{
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #CCCCCC 50%, #FFFFFF);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
div:before{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EEEEEE, #666666 50%, #EEEEEE);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

**Using a single element:**

With just a single element (no pseudo/real elements), we can sort of achieve this<sup>*</sup> using `background-image` but not with `border-image`. It is a lot more complex because we have to create a gradient strip for each of the 8 (4 outer + 4 inner) borders and then place them accordingly.

<sup>* - This doesn't produce the exact same output as border-image but is close enough.</sup>

```css
div{
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #CCCCCC 50%, #FFFFFF),
    linear-gradient(to right, #FFFFFF, #FFFFFF),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #CCCCCC 50%, #FFFFFF),
    linear-gradient(to right, #EEEEEE, #EEEEEE),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #EEEEEE, #666666 50%, #EEEEEE),
    linear-gradient(to right, #EEEEEE, #EEEEEE),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #EEEEEE, #666666 50%, #EEEEEE);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 5px, 5px 100%, 100% 5px, 5px 100%, calc(100% - 10px) 5px, 5px calc(100% - 10px), calc(100% - 10px) 5px, 5px calc(100% - 10px);
  background-position: 0px 0px, 100% 0px, 0px 100%, 0px 0px, 5px 5px, calc(100% - 5px), 0px calc(100% - 5px), 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```